# Awk: Create Group by report?

Tags: awk

I have an ASCII file that contains tab-delimited data like this:

```
Test_Version=2.5.3  Model-Manufacturer=D12-500
Test_Version=2.5.3  Model-Manufacturer=D12-500
Test_Version=2.6.3  Model-Manufacturer=H23-600
Test_Version=2.6.3  Model-Manufacturer=HR21-100
Test_Version=2.6.3  Model-Manufacturer=HR21-100
Test_Version=2.6.4  Model-Manufacturer=R16-300
```

I want to create with Awk a report that counts "Model-Manufacturer" grouped by "Test_Version":

```
Test_Version        Model-Manufacturer   Count-Model-Manufacturer
2.5.3               D12-500              2
2.6.3               HR21-100             2
2.6.3               H23-600              1
2.6.4               R16-300              1
```

This is what I started with but it's not working...

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";} {vercounts[$1]=vercounts[$1]+1;mdlcounts[$2]=mdlcounts[$2]+1}
END     {for (key in vercounts)
            printf "%s\t%d\n", key, vercounts[key];} {for (key in mdlcounts) printf "%s\t%d\n", key, mdlcounts[key];}
' data_file
```

Is it possible? How would you go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it, what you really want to do is to count the number of repeated lines. Leaving out the pretty printing, all you really need is:

```
{ counts[$0]++; } 
END { for (key in counts) { print key, counts[key]; } }
```

Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Awesome! Your solution worked like a charm. Thanks so much!! I can only aspire to become a knowledgeable as you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you are expecting.  But I think

```
{a[$0]++}  
END {for (i in a)  { print i, a[i]}  
}
```

will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '\t' '
  {
    split($1, ver, /=/)
    split($2, model, /=/)
    count[ver[2] FS model[2]]++
  }
  END {for (key in count) print key FS count[key]}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following piece of awk snippet will give exactly what you are looking for

```
awk -F" " '{ vercounts[$0]+=1} END { for ( i in vercounts ) { a=i; gsub("Test_Version=|Model-Manufacturer=","",a) ; print a,vercounts[i]} }' file_name
```

```
2.6.4  R16-300 1
2.6.3  HR21-100 2
2.6.3  H23-600 1
2.5.3  D12-500 2
```